# error in finding queryselector in test cases angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been writing test cases in Angular 6 for my register component.

So far I have initiallized the component
but whenever I am trying to access the values in the registeruser function I am getting error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
here is my report 
[image]

my spec file is as follow

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register.component';
import { FormGroup, FormsModule, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {RegisterService} from '../../services/register.service';
import {ReqObjectModel} from '../../interfaces/request-object-model.interface'; 
import {MatSelectModule, MatInputModule, MatCardModule, MatButtonModule,MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; 
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

fdescribe('RegisterComponent', () => {
  let component: RegisterComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<RegisterComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ RegisterComponent ],
      imports: [ RouterTestingModule,FormsModule ,MatSelectModule, HttpClientModule, MatInputModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, MatCardModule, MatButtonModule,MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule,RouterModule],
      providers:[{provide: RegisterService}]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RegisterComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create instance of RegisterComponent', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('Register called', () => {
    var event = new Event('click');
    console.log(event);
    component.registerUser(event);
  });

  

});
```

Comment: At the micro level, your `new Event` doesn't actually have a `target` element attached to it. At the macro level, this is a very implementation-dependent test; it would be better to trigger a click event *on the actual element* via e.g. the `fixture.nativeElement`, rather than calling the handler method directly, so you're testing the *behaviour* rather than the specific way it currently works. Also you should replace the real `RegisterService` with a test double, as it's a collaborator.

Comment: Please, just don't do that logic in that way. You have a lot of ways to get the values of your forms, don't use a queryselector, love yourself a bit more. Use reactive forms, template forms, dynamic forms or two ways binding, follow the docs.

Comment: The docs specifically discourage passing the whole event, in fact: https://angular.io/guide/user-input#passing-event-is-a-dubious-practice

Answer (score 0):

That is simply because are you are calling `component.registerUser(event);` and it doesn't find any values for email etc and hence querySelector gets null. You need to set this value. You can try something like -

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RegisterComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled : HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    //you need to define all the fields values used in your function registerUser
    email= compiled.querySelector('search-box > input')
    email.value = 'fake-search-query'
    email.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture .detectChanges();
})
```

Comment: it says cannot find name 'compiled', any idea?

Comment: Did you change the css `search-box > input` as per your code?